# How to align three charts with stacked bars and with captions, center alignment and main caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

**The problem**

I  need a chart like this (this was from one research paper):

[image]

**What I have**

Currently my output is displayed below:
I tried to create 3 charts using the above reference diagram. However, when I'm doing that on Overleaf with my `IEEEtran` document, I see that the charts cross the page boundary. If you could make a minimal example I would appreciate it a lot.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 3},width=10cm,height=25cm]
        \nextgroupplot[
            height=7cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        x post scale=1.3,   
        scale only axis,
        enlarge y limits=0.75, 
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=6mm, y=14mm,
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        nodes near coords style={
            yshift={
                ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2) , 13pt,13pt)
            }
             }, % shift down the third and sixth node       
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        legend style={at={(-0.5,1.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,font=\normalsize},
        ]

        \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
        %\legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}

        \nextgroupplot[
            height=7cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        x post scale=1.3,   
        scale only axis,
        enlarge y limits=0.75, 
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=6mm, y=14mm,
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        nodes near coords style={
            yshift={
                ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2) , 13pt,13pt)
            }
             }, % shift down the third and sixth node       
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        legend style={at={(-0.5,1.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,font=\normalsize},
        ]

        \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};

        \nextgroupplot[
            height=7cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        x post scale=1.3,   
        scale only axis,
        enlarge y limits=0.75, 
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=6mm, y=14mm,
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        nodes near coords style={
            yshift={
                ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2) , 13pt,13pt)
            }
             }, % shift down the third and sixth node       
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        legend style={at={(-0.5,1.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,font=\normalsize},
        ]

        \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};

        


       \legend{Action selection, Benchmark learned policies,Calculate rewards,Collect experience,Environment Interactions, Gradient synchronization}
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For width of each diagram you prescribed `\textwidth`, consequently is visible only the first diagram, the second and third diagram are pushed to outside of page.
- That all diagrams will be visible, set their width to `0.3\textwidth`.
- Image should be inserted in `figure*` float.
- It is not clear if diagrams titles had to be referable. So far I assume, that not, so they are added as diagrams title.

Some of topic suggestion:

- image style specification move to `groupplot` option.
- reduce font size of `nodes near coord`, `xticklabel` and in `legend`
- legend write in three columns

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 3}, 
    width=0.33\textwidth, height=7cm,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
    scale only axis,
    x post scale=0.85,
    enlarge y limits=0.6,
    ytick=data,
%
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
    xtick={0,20,...,100},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
    xticklabel style={font=\small},
%    
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, 
                             yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 2,\plotnum == 4), -14pt, 14pt)}
                            }, % shift down the third and sixth node
%
    title style = {at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
                  legend columns=3, font=\small,
                  cells={anchor=west},
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}
                  }
                    ]
\nextgroupplot[title=(a) title,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=5mm,
    y=14mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};

\nextgroupplot[title=(b) title,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=5mm,
    y=14mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
    \legend{Action selection,   Benchmark learned policies, Calculate rewards,
                    Collect experience, Environment Interactions,   Gradient synchronization},

\nextgroupplot[title=(c) title,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=5mm,
    y=14mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Caption text}
\label{fig:?}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders)