# x axis labels are getting repeated twice for a bar-chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Problem 1:
I am trying to generate a bar-chart with 3 bars for each chart. But as you can see from the below output, my x-axis labels are getting repeated twice.
X axis labels = {3-6, 6-12, 12-24}

Problem 2:
When I compile the code on overleaf, I get the picture in the center in a full and when I paste the code in another document, it occupies lot of space (as the whole pdf page is being coped to another document). Is there any way that when I compile the project, I just get a pdf download which just confined to that image?

**Problem 2 output**

[image]

**Problem 1 output:**

[image]

**Latex code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    legend columns=-1,
                    %bar width=1pt, % Width of the bar
                    %, % Distance between the centers of the bars
                    symbolic x coords={3-6, 6-12, 12-24},
                     enlarge x limits={abs=0.6cm},
                     width=1.2\textwidth,
                     %xtick={3,6,12,24},
                    height=0.8\textheight,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=15,
                    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
   nodes near coords align={vertical},
                     xlabel={x},
                     ylabel={y},
                     % The distance between the center of the first bar and the left edge
                    %enlarge y limits=false,
                    legend entries={{\color{olive}{\tiny Random}},{\color{orange}{\tiny ++Cost}},{\color{teal}{\tiny ++FTE}}},
                    legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
                    footnotesize,
                    ybar legend,
                    legend image code/.code={%
                     \draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                         },
                    % area legend, % This is the alternate option
                    group style={
                    group size=3 by 1,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left}]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MADDPG}]
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                    %\addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MATD3}]
                     \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                   % \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MASAC}]
            `       \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                   % \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ref{CombinedLegendBar}
        \caption{Triage++ Performance}
        \label{PlusPlusCombinedBar}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your question is not entirely clear, for example, how you insert this image in your real (final) document?
- For figure positioning on page, try to use placement position options, i.e. instead `\begin{figure}` write `\begin{figure}[ht]` or `\begin{figure}[!ht]`.
- After cleanup your `groupplot` settings as is done in MWE below, and a after wee bit reorganizing your figure code, the compilation on the local MiKTeX installation as well in the Overleaf gives the same result.
- The clean-up is done in spirit of my answer on your previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660809/how-to-align-three-charts-with-stacked-bars-and-with-captions-center-alignment) (no need to add `xtick` option):

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=3 by 1,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    horizontal sep=6mm,
            },
%
    width=0.27\linewidth, %height=4cm,
    scale only axis,
    title style = {font=\small},
%
    enlarge x limits=0.3,
    xlabel={x},     ylabel={y},
    symbolic x coords={3-6, 6-12, 12-24},
    ytick={0,2,...,12},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    ymin=0,     ymax=12,
%
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={yshift=-3pt, font=\scriptsize},
%
    legend entries = {\color{olive}{Random},
                      \color{orange}{++Cost},
                      \color{teal}{++FTE}},
    legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
    legend image code/.code={\draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.33)},
                  below,
                  legend columns=-1,
                  font=\footnotesize,
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}
                  }
                    ]
\nextgroupplot[title=MADDPG]
    \addplot[ybar, fill=olive]  coordinates {  (3-6,   6.886) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates {  (6-12,  8.501) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal]   coordinates {  (12-24,10.179) };

\nextgroupplot[title=MATD3]
    \addplot[ybar, fill=olive]  coordinates {  (3-6,   6.886) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates {  (6-12,  8.501) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal]   coordinates {  (12-24,10.179) };

\nextgroupplot[title=MASAC]
    \addplot[ybar, fill=olive]  coordinates {  (3-6,   6.886) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates {  (6-12,  8.501) };
    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal]   coordinates {  (12-24,10.179) };
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \ref{CombinedLegendBar}
\caption{Triage++ Performance}
\label{PlusPlusCombinedBar}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Problem 1: Adding the xtick command with the symbolic labels (see below) did the trick for me.

Regarding Problem 2: If I understood correctly, replacing the article class from document to standalone did it for me (I had to remove the figure environment + the caption)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    legend columns=-1,
                    %bar width=1pt, % Width of the bar
                    %, % Distance between the centers of the bars
                    symbolic x coords={3-6, 6-12, 12-24},
                     enlarge x limits={abs=0.6cm},
                     width=1.2\textwidth,
                    xtick={3-6, 6-12, 12-24},
                    height=0.8\textheight,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=15,
                    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
   nodes near coords align={vertical},
                     xlabel={x},
                     ylabel={y},
                     % The distance between the center of the first bar and the left edge
                    %enlarge y limits=false,
                    legend entries={{\color{olive}{\tiny Random}},{\color{orange}{\tiny ++Cost}},{\color{teal}{\tiny ++FTE}}},
                    legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
                    footnotesize,
                    ybar legend,
                    legend image code/.code={%
                     \draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                         },
                    % area legend, % This is the alternate option
                    group style={
                    group size=3 by 1,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left}]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MADDPG}]
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                    %\addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MATD3}]
                     \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                   % \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize MASAC}]
            `       \addplot[ybar, fill=olive] coordinates {  (3-6, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates { (6-12, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, fill=teal] coordinates {  (12-24, 10.179)};
                   % \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    % \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]